# Error: call super outside of class constructor

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I try to call parent method but I get error:

> Error: call super outside of class constructor

My example :

```
class xo{
    cool(x){
        console.log(`parent init${x}`)
    }
}
class boo extends xo{
    cool(val){
        super(val);
        console.log(`child init${x}`)
    }
}

x = new boo;
```

Answer (score 17):

You call not the parent **method**, but parent **constructor** which is not valid call outside of the constructor. You need to use `super.cool(val);` instead of `super(val)`;

```
class xo{

    cool(x) {
        console.log(`parent init${x}`)
    }

}

class boo extends xo {

    cool(val) {
        super.cool(val);
        console.log(`child init${x}`)
    }

}

x = new boo();
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `super.cool(val)` instead to call the `cool` method on the super class. `super()` invokes the super class' constructor.